# Бесконечная сумма C

Tags: c, циклы, математика, ряды, численные-методы

Каким образом можно вычислить бесконечную сумму с значением, которые по модулю превышают заданную точность s = 10^-4 (0.0001). У меня есть код,но я не понимаю как прикрутить сюда точность.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    int k,j,l;
    double x,sum = 0,sum2;
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    double inf = INFINITY;
    
    if (x >= -2 && x <= 2){
     for (k = 1;k <= inf ;k++){
         for (sum;sum >= 0.0001 && sum <= 2;)
            sum += pow(-1,k-1)*pow(x,3*k+1) / (3*k*k) +1;
            printf("Число %f",sum);

            
}
}
    else{
            printf("Error! ");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не могу молчать! :)

Когда я вижу вот такое — `sum += pow(-1,k-1)*pow(x,3*k+1) / (3*k*k) +1;` — пусть даже для записанной вами формулы "делить на 3kk+1!" — у меня, как говорил капитан из "72 метра", начинает чесаться в самых нескромных местах. Посмотрите сами, на что вы делите? Не менее прекрасно и даже уникально сравнение `k <= inf`... Вы всерьез намеревались дождаться, когда `k` превзойдет бесконечность? :) Даже не будем вдаваться в то, что это всего 32 бита... О применении `pow` для чередования знака на этом фоне я уже просто молчу — мелочь, не стоящая упоминания.

Мне все же кажется, что тут потеряны скобки, и ваша функция имеет вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте найти отношение двух соседних членов сами. Как только вы его найдете, все сразу очень упростится:

```
double f(double x, double eps)
{
    double x3 = x*x*x;
    double t = x3*x/6, s = t;
    for(int k = 2; abs(t) > eps; ++k)
        s += t *= -x3*(k-1)/k/(k+1);
    return s;
}
```

Кстати, непонятно, зачем у вас условие от -2 до 2 — ряд сходится при любых `x`.

Comment: Приветствую!Спасибо за ответ.X это вводимое число для условия суммы

Comment: Это я понимаю :), недаром он у меня аргумент функции. Но почему вы ограничиваетесь интервалом [-2;2]?

Comment: Таковы условия данной мне задачи)

Comment: Вы бы точно и полностью ее сформулировали...

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так:

```
k = 0;
while(True) {
   k++;
   t = pow(-1,k-1)* ...
   if (abs(t)<0.0001) break;
   sum += t;
}
```

Только для вычисления `t` нужна правильная формула, на картинке сомнительный знаменатель, а ещё лучше вычислять очередной член рекуррентно (на основе предыдущего)